# ASP.NET MVC3 Windows Authentication require from Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I'm looking to create a site that will utilize our Active Directory login system. So in an experiment, I created a project with Windows Authentication and tried logging in from other locations. One machine used my user I was logged in. That's great. I logged in from a Mac, it asked me to authenticate. Excellent.

My concern however, is logging in from a computer that isn't logged in as an AD user (and instead as a local admin user). So instead of the user being displayed as AD(USER) it is MACHINE\USER.

Is there any way to require my application to have authenticated users from solely the AD space? Or am I better off making my own authentication logic?

And in a side subject (I haven't done any searching on it, so feel free to avoid this question), is there a way to permit only a certain group of AD users from accessing the website?

(Please note I'm new to both AD and ASP so if I'm simply missing certain terms I'd be glad to do more research)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That awkward moment when you ask for help, do a bit more searching and answer it yourself.

http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/343407-using-web-config-allow-access-domain-users-only

So I did this:

```
<authorization>
  <allow roles="AD\Group.Name" />
  <deny users="?" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```